# Return Array in Self-Calling Function in VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to figure out how to return a string array in a function that calls itself. It is a function that looks through all folders and subfolders within a specific path to generate a list of text files and where they are located. Right now, the subroutine is `All_Folder`. I have previously tried making `All_Folder` a function, and trying to return the value from the function, but that has gotten me nowhere. This is my code now:

```
Public file_locations() As String
Sub Some_Subroutine()
    Dim pathway As String: pathway = "C:\Users"
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    All_Folder FileSystem.GetFolder(pathway)

    ...

End Sub
Public Sub All_Folder(Folder)
    Dim filetype as string: filetype = "*.txt"
    Dim Counter As Integer: Counter = 0
    Dim SubFolder: Dim File
    For Each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        All_Folder SubFolder
    Next
    For Each File in Folder.Files
        If Dir(Folder & "\" & filetype) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve file_locations(Counter)
            file_locations(Counter) = CallByName(File, Path, VbGet)
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is that every time this function is ran, the output in `file_locations` is always overwritten by what is in the next called directory.

I have the list by the end of the subroutine `All_Folder`, I just need to be able to store/append it to the current `file_locations` list.

Comment: I don't see any function, a sub does not return anytthing

Comment: Every time you hit `All_Folder` you reset `Counter` to zero, so each time through you're just writing to the same array locations.

Comment: If you want to run `All_Folder` more than once then make your `Counter` a global variable too: `Public Counter As Long` and remove `Dim Counter As Integer: Counter = 0`

Comment: Your method of checking the file type is also a bit off - all it does is check whether there's at least one txt file in the folder being processed.

Comment: Since you're using FSO you could use the `GetExtensionName` method to check the file type.

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams and @PeH. All I needed was to set my `Counter` as a global variable.

Comment: Make an array local to the module (above your subs) when calling the function recursively (calls itself without any idea how many calls will be made, until a condition is met) add your directory:filename or the full path to the array as a string.  In recursion it will be built from the bottom up.  You could always just loop this in a directory path until there are no more files and avoid the recursion.  But if you do not know how many files or folders are in a directory it would be a good case for recursion (think tree structure).

Comment: See here for an example of how to do this non-recursively - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227570/convert-spreadsheets-from-folder-to-pdf-save-to-different-location/54227683#54227683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) and [PeH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%E1%B4%87%CA%9C) suggested, I had not set my `Counter` as a global variable. Here would be the updated code:

```
Public file_locations() As String
Public Counter As Integer
Sub Some_Subroutine()
    Dim pathway As String: pathway = "C:\Users"
    Counter = 0
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    All_Folder FileSystem.GetFolder(pathway)

    ...

End Sub
Public Sub All_Folder(Folder)
    Dim filetype as string: filetype = "*.txt"
    Dim SubFolder: Dim File
    For Each SubFolder in Folder.SubFolders
        All_Folder SubFolder
    Next
    For Each File in Folder.Files
        If Dir(Folder & "\" & filetype) <> "" Then
            ReDim Preserve file_locations(Counter)
            file_locations(Counter) = CallByName(File, Path, VbGet)
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks to you two for helping me out.