# Scan folder for .jpg filenames, match the filenames in Excel Worksheet Cells and paste them in the cells

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Need the code to scan the folder `Z:\Images` and insert matching images in the excel cells:

[image]

The below code is for inserting in consecutive cells, not random cells. I dont know how to modify it for my requirement.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngCell As Range

    strFolder = "C:\Users\Domenic\Pictures\Saved Pictures\" 'change the path accordingly
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If

    Set rngCell = Range("E1") 'starting cell

    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.png", vbNormal) 'filter for .png files

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .Left = rngCell.Left
            .Top = rngCell.Top
            .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

The code is able to fetch data I need (imagefiles), but it is pasting the images in one column -- Range ("E1").

I need to write an if condition to match the imagenames in the excel and paste image when a match is found.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264407/return-array-in-self-calling-function - See if the answer in this link won't help you get the list of files you want. You'll have to modify it to fit your needs, but it should return a `Variant` with the complete list. From there, you could sort the list and place each entry in the list into the cell you wanted.

Comment: that wasn't helpful unfortunately.